# Use OAuth Bearer Token instead of PAT in Ajax calls to VSTS API

Tags: ajax, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've successfully got my ASP.NET (MVC5) application reading from and writing to our VSTS work items in C# on the server side.

However, for the best user experience I really want to make some updates using Ajax. I've been able to get this working perfectly using a Personal Access Token (PAT) created under my own account. For example, this works fine:

```
var vstsAuthHeader = { "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "abcd...123") }

function updateRoadmapGroup(featureId, newRoadmapGroup) {
var patchDocument = [{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/fields/CustomScrum.RoadmapGroupID",
    "value": newRoadmapGroup
}];
var patchValue = JSON.stringify(patchDocument);

$.ajax({
    method: "PATCH",
    url: "https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workitems/" + featureId + "?api-version=" + apiVersion,
    contentType: "application/json-patch+json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(vstsAuthHeader);
    },
    processData: false,
    data: patchValue,
    error: function (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

};

Once that was working, I assumed that moving to using OAuth instead of my PAT would be easy. Something like changing the first line of the code listed above to:

```
var vstsAuthHeader = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + btoa("" + ":" + accessToken) }
```

This doesn't work - I get the error "401 (Unauthorized)", and when I delve a little deeper the full error is:

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

I've tried so many variations of the Ajax call, but none work. I've tried adding

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + btoa("" + ":" + accessToken));
},
```

which seems closer to some examples of similar things I've found online, but doesn't work.

I've tried both of the above methods without the `btoa` function, which I believe is converting the token to Base64, just passing using the raw accessToken value. And I've tried a dozen other things, always with the same result.

My question is how do I update the VSTS items in an Ajax call with an OAuth Bearer Token in the same way that I'm able to do with a PAT?

Comment: Is your VSTS account backed by an Azure AD? And your sign in email address is both Work Account and Microsoft Account?

Comment: Well that's a good question. The whole "VSTS by Azure AD" thing confuses me somewhat, but I looked into it as I saw it mentioned in the VSTS API documentation and it doesn't seem as if the VSTS account is backed by Azure AD. Do you know of a definitive way to know? I'm using a Microsoft Account for VSTS, there is no Work Account in the mix. Does the fact that the PAT works not indicate that my account has the correct permissions anyway?

Comment: You can check it from the settings of your account(https:/account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_home/settings). No, the permission of PAT is inherited fro your account. If your account doesn't have the correct permission, PAT won't work.

Comment: And if you are using Microsoft Account, the identity on the 401 error page should like this "Windows Live ID\youremailaddress", please check this.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT It seems that our VSTS account was indeed backed by Azure Active Directory. When I hit the 401 page the identity is a string of letters and numbers (like and SID), not my Microsoft Account username. Using AAD is overkill for our team anyway, so I disconnected the VSTS account from Azure AD and now my Ajax calls work perfectly! Thanks for your help! Feel free to add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the identity is different for the same sign in address when it is used as both Microsoft Account and Work Account. And the id of the identity is also different for the same work account address in different domains. So if you get 401 error with OAuth token, it could be caused by the identity you used to issue the token is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these code:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/209?api-version=1.0',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        var b = "Bearer [auth token]";

                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", b);
                    },
                }).done(function (data) {

                }).error(function (e) {

                });
```

On the other hand, make sure you check the related scope (e.g. Work Item) when create application in VSTS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given it a try but still no joy, I still get 401 Unauthorized. The application in VSTS has the scope `vso.work_full` so I think that should be sufficient. Your example is for a GET request. Do you think it should also work for a PATCH request? That's what the VSTS documentation says I need to use.

Comment: @PhilipStratford It works for a PATCH request. Do you get a new OAuth access token? The token will be expired after 1 hour.

Comment: I check the expiry time of the user's token every time they access the page in my web application and refresh it if it's expired. I guess it could have expired after I've been testing the page for an hour but it should work initially.

Comment: @PhilipStratford Try it with PostMan tool and check the result. (Select No Auth and specify the header in Headers tab: Key is Authorization; Value is Bearer [token])

Comment: I still get 401 Not Authorized in Postman. The returned Body in HTML is a page saying "The user <myuser> is not authorized to access this resource". I'm using the same account as I use every day in VSTS which owns the VSTS account. I've uploaded a screenshot of the response here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoxUcQPbia2lmuFRvLYI3HBCQP6-Dw

Comment: @PhilipStratford Try to get the token through this project: [ASP.NET web app (OAuth sample)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive? Try it with a new VSTS applicatio and check the results.

Comment: Sorry it's taken a few days to create another test application, and thanks for your continued help with this. I've taken the OAuthWebSample project from that GitHub repo and made the bare minimum of alterations to demonstrate my problem. It's available here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoxUcQPbia2lmuIamdoBGn0fp3sMHA. I've redacted sensitive info from this version, but the published version successfully retrieves a list of Features and yet fails to update any data with an Ajax call, just like my real app. Error is: "TF400813: The user 'abc-123' is not authorized to access this resource".

Comment: Try to use fiddler tool to capture the request and check it.