# Is there a way to get user permissions in a specific Azure Devops Project using rest api?

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Hi I want to check the permissions of a user in a specific Azure Devops Project. Is there a possible way to get it? As far as I know project level permission is different than organization level permissions. Thanks.

Already test some several rest apis but still I can't have the project level permission.

Comment: Hi abby What is the result of your test, is my method feasible?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no out-of-the-box rest api to get the user's permission in project.

To achieve this demand, you can use this rest api :

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
    "contributionIds": ["ms.vss-admin-web.org-admin-permissions-pivot-data-provider"],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "subjectDescriptor": "msa.ZjE1ZTk0NmMtOTI4OS03Mjg5LTljMGUtMDIwMTdlYmM2Nzhj",
            "sourcePage": {
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxxx/_settings/permissions",
                "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route",
                "routeValues": {
                    "action": "Execute",
                    "adminPivot": "permissions",
                    "controller": "ContributedPage",
                    "project": "XXX",
                    "serviceHost": "0933e8b2-f504-4b7e-9e9e-xxxxx (xxx)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can track this rest api by press `F12` in  browser then select `Network` .Then looking for the record that response body included returned permission. From this record you can get the rest api and request body.
[image]

I tested with postman , with this api ,I can successful get user's permission in project. As shown below:
[image]

Comment: Agree with @Hugh, and you can get user's descriptor id by https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1. You can get the more detailed information in https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll be testing this out today and I'll let you know the results once I'm done testing :)

Comment: The results says that I am not authorized to access the said resource

Comment: Do you add the PAT as Basic Auth in Authoriaztion?

Comment: If you  use an IE or Edeg browser, the request body should have a display, as shown in the image in the answer.

Comment: I am actually using this api https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2 and it gives me the user permission in a specific project but the problem it is showing custom in some of the projects

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT unfortunately it is giving me this error TF400813: The user '12323123123' is not authorized to access this resource.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT : I did try to use your method using PAT token as my authorization and it works but when using OAuth its response is the one that I have mentioned above

Comment: If you get 401 error with OAuth token, it could be caused by the identity you used to issue the token is incorrect. You can refer to the answer in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978479/use-oauth-bearer-token-instead-of-pat-in-ajax-calls-to-vsts-api)

Comment: I got the idea how to access the api's which are not documented using the network tab and obtained what I wanted

Comment: After a long search I did NOT find a way to do this for Azure DevOps Server 2020.