# Using OAuth 2 to authenticate to Azure DevOps REST APIs fails with TF400813 (user not authorized)

Tags: azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

I am following the documentation posted here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops).

I have a react-based webapp and a powershell-based function app, both in Azure.  My function app is presently using a personal access token created with my work account (AAD) credentials, which is not desirable. My goal is to use OAuth2 to authorize my function app to make code changes to a GIT repository on behalf of a webapp user. When I follow the instructions above, I am able to acquire what appears to be a valid authorization code, access token, and refresh token, I receive the following error message from Azure DevOps:

> TF400813: The user 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff' is not authorized to access this resource.
> …
> 401 - Uh-oh, you do not have access.
> The request requires authentication.
> 4/21/2021 12:04:16 AM (UTC)
> ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
> Sign out and login with different account

I have obscured the guids in the example above, but the user GUID appears to match the GUID I find for my work account when I call the legacy identity APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read%20identities?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).
I created my application (https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register) with the same scopes that I used to create my personal access token.  I verified in my dev.azure.com profile that my application is listed as an authorized OAuth app, as expected after creating the authorization request and receiving the authorization code.

The error message above is confusing to me.  It says that the user (me) is not authorized to access the resource but also says that the authentication failed.  Which is it?

Is this a problem with how I am acquiring my authorization/access tokens?  Am I somehow using the wrong account?  Are my scopes wrong?

### Reproduction of Problem

Here is the state from my registered application:

```
My application state:
{
    "scopes": "vso.code_full vso.code_status vso.graph_manage vso.identity_manage vso.threads_full vso.tokens",
    "tokenUrl": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token",
    "state": "foo",
    "authCallback": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/oauth-callback",
    "clientSecret": "S.S.S-S-S",
    "authUrl": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize",
    "appWebsite": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/",
    "appSecret": "S",
    "appId": "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF"
}
```

Step 1. Authorize the application.

```
I invoke the following auth URI from an in-private browser.
I authenticate my work account, and authorize the application for the requested scopes.
I can verify the app is an authorized oauth app in my dev.azure.com profile.

https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF&response_type=Assertion&state=foo&scope=vso.code_full%20vso.code_status%20vso.graph_manage%20vso.identity_manage%20vso.threads_full%20vso.tokens&redirect_uri=https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/oauth-callback

I receive an authcode, "A.A.A-A-A-A" (shown decoded/obfuscated below):
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "x5t": "....."
}
{
    "cid": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "csi": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "nameid": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "iss": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "aud": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "nbf": 1618438026,
    "exp": 1776204426
}
```

Step 2. Request the access token and refresh token from my powershell function app:

```
I make a rest api call to the token endpoint:
  "Uri": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token"
  "Method": "POST"
  "ContentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  "Body": "client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=S.S.S-S-S&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=A.A.A-A-A-A&redirect_uri=https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/oauth-callback"

…and I get the following JSON response:
Token Response:
{
    "access_token": "X.X.X-X-X-X-X-X-X",
    "token_type": "jwt-bearer"
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "refresh_token": "R.R.R-R-R-R",
    "scope": "vso.code_full vso.code_status vso.graph_manage vso.identity_manage vso.threads_full vso.tokens vso.authorization_grant"
}

Yielding the following JWT for the access token:
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "x5t": "....."
}
{
    "nameid": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "scp": "vso.code_full vso.code_status vso.graph_manage vso.identity_manage vso.threads_full vso.tokens",
    "aui": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "appid": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "iss": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "aud": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "nbf": 1618963456,
    "exp": 1618967056
}
```

Step 3. Make a DevOps REST API call.

```
In this case, I am requesting a list of respositories in my org/project:
  "Uri": "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproj/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0"
  "Method": "GET"
  "Headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer X.X.X-X-X-X-X-X-X"}

This is where things go wrong.  DevOps returns a 401 error indicating that my account is not authorized.
  TF400813: The user &#39;ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff&#39; is not authorized to access this resource.
```

If I make the exact same http GET from Step 3, but I substitute my PAT with identical scopes as the registered application, the call succeeds.  The PAT seems to be created with the exact same profile/account that is authorized in Step 1.

Comment: Here are some tickets([case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978479/use-oauth-bearer-token-instead-of-pat-in-ajax-calls-to-vsts-api)[case2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tf400813-the-user-is-not-authorized-to-access-this-5/738745)) with similar issue you can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be observed when the organization admins have disabled OAuth in the settings. The relevant option can be viewed by any member of the org at e.g. https://dev.azure.com/contoso/_settings/organizationPolicy

[image: Screenshot of the relevant settings page]

Sadly there is no better indication of this for the app or the user, as far as I can see.

Your app can still ask the user for authorization, all OAuth operations succeed, a seemingly valid access token gets returned, but then it simply does not work and returns 401 from all APIs, even if a PAT with the same scope(s) works fine.